# Maven server authentication as profile properties

Tags: authentication, maven-2, settings, profiles

I am trying to setup a shared authentication system on a build server.
We have several maven projects that declares how the deployment should be done regarding the different teams that we have (each team has its own authentication user/password):

```
<profile>
  <id>release-profile</id>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>rep-releases</id>
        <name>rep-releases</name>
        <url>http://somewhere-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>rep-snapshots</id>
        <name>rep-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://somewhere-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
</profile>
```

Then I declare in the settings.xml the authentification to the declared servers as following:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>rep-releases</id>
    <username>${release.user.name}</username>
    <password>${release.user.password}</password>
  </server>     
  <server>
    <id>rep-snapshots</id>
    <username>${release.user.name}</username>
    <password>${release.user.password}</password>
  </server>      
</servers>
```

Finally, depending on the projects I want to deploy I have several profiles defined in the settings.xml of the build server:

```
<profile>
  <id>dep-team1</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <release.user.name>team1-user</release.user.name>
    <release.user.password>team1-password</release.user.password>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

The problem is that when doing a deploy of the project I got an authentication error (HTTP 401) like the following:

```
Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file: http://......./my-project-0.2-20090423.123247-3.pom. Return code is: 401
```

If I modify the server authentication by replacing the properties with the user/password of the team, all is working fine.

Don't the tags <servers><server> accept values as properties?

How do others setup their build system in order to achieve the same?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** I am using hudson, a solution for me can be to install several time maven2 and have duplicated settings (except user/password) for each team and tie each project to the good maven installation. I must admit that this solution does not enchant me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most direct method if you have multiple teams and thus multiple auth schemes, is just use a different id in the distributionManagement. So instead of rep-releases/rep-snapshots, you can have team1-repo / team2-repo (there's generally no value in separating the auth between release and snapshots...particularly if you use a [repo manager](http://nexus.sonatype.org) with good security controls)

Then in the settings of your build machine, just define a user and password for each team for the build server.

This approach does have a draw back that it would mess up inheritence if you defined the repos in a single corporate pom...but if you have a team level pom it would be easy.

Another thought is why does the same build machine need to login as a different person when doing builds? Shouldn't that build machine have mostly full access?

Comment: You're right Brian, the easiest way to achieve what we want is probably to give full rights to the build machine at least to deliver to all the snapshots repos. Each team keeping it's own credentials to make the releases. I think we will go this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not see how dep-team1 profile is connected to the distributionManagement tag - it seems to need release-profile to be active.

Second, I have my profile element structured a bit differently (see, there is no distributionManagement tag within). Not sure if it makes the difference.:

```
<profile>
  <id>release-profile</id>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</profile>
```

Here is the distribution management:

```
<project>
   <distributionManagement>

    <repository>
      <id>releases</id>
      <url>http://myurl/releases</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <url>http://myurl/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>

  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: 1. If you do not use maven to deliver your project of course that you do not need any distributionManagement tag.
2. Of course that in my deliver process all required profiles are activated.

Comment: I do use maven to deliver my project and it works. Initially I had the same "error deploying artifacts" error, but then I figured it out.
My distributionManagement element is not a part of the profile, but rather part of the project (which is more logical, btw).

Comment: We have hundreds of projects in our company, with several R&D throw the world so having the setups in profiles ease the sharing between teams.
But all of this does help in having a correct resolution of the server login/pass with properties.